# Stop user multi-clicking on edittext to open several dialogues

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-edittext, android-datepicker

I have a very simple question. I have an `EditText`, that when clicked on, opens a `DatePickerDialog`. However, repeatedly clicking on the `EditText` opens several dialogs. Is there any way to restrict the user from doing this, so that only one dialogue is displayed regardless of how many times the `EditText` is clicked on?

Here is my `EditText` in my XML file:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etSetDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spDifficultyLevel"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_calendar_view"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
    android:hint=" Set Date"
/>
```

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Where user selects date, launch datepicker on click
 */

public void selectDate() {
    etSetDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //launch datepicker
            DialogFragment dialogFragment = new StartDatePicker();
            dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                "start_date_picker");
        }
    });
}

public class StartDatePicker extends DialogFragment implements
      DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int startYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int startMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int startDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the date picker
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,
            startYear, startMonth, startDay);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: Set flag variable, and disable your edit-text after one click using setting flag to false.

Comment: Editing your original question to include your code would be clearer.

Comment: but if they want to then click on the edittext again, I'll need to reopen the dialgoue box and doing that would restrict them from doing so

Answer (score 1):

```
int flag = 0;
etSetDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //launch datepicker

            if(flag == 0)
            {
            DialogFragment dialogFragment = new StartDatePicker();
            dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    "start_date_picker");
             flag = 1;
            }

        }

    });
```

and when you dismiss dialog then again set `flag = 0`.

Comment: the problem is the flag variable cannot be accessed without being declared final, and then cannot be reassigned to 1 within the if statement

Comment: uploaded code at top, there is no direct way of dismissing a datepicker

Comment: hey would u check that method exist for dialog such as 'dialogFragment.isShowing();'??? let me know

Answer (score 1):

First check the fragment manager to see if the fragment exists:

```
Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("start_date_picker");
if(frag == null) {
    frag = new StartDatePicker();
    frag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "start_date_picker");
}
```

If frag is not null then the dialog is showing.